# How to Pass a Variable in the vue.js Router "Next" Route

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vue-router

I am using vue.js router in order to re-direct users to the home page (via "next") if they try to access certain pages which require authentication without having a cookie (which is set upon authentication). I would like to pass a variable to the home page within the next route (i.e. next({ name: 'Home' }, variable)), but I am not finding the proper syntax to implement this.

```
 router.beforeEach((to, from, next) => {
   if (to.meta.requiresAuth) {
     var cookie = document.cookie
     if (cookie === '') {
       next({ name: 'Home' })
     } else {
       next()
     }
   }
 })
```

Thank you. J

Comment: Why not just use `state` for that?

Comment: If it was just about redirection then `next({path: '/home'})` would probably be good enough. Any reason why you need to pass that variable other than redirection?

Comment: Thank you @Jakub A Suplicki. Yes, I wish to let the user know that he needs to authenticate anew. Otherwise, he is simply redirected without knowing the root cause. The variable would consist of a flag sent to the home page, so that it knows what message to display.

Comment: Thank you @Chris. I am not using "state" on my site, for I only need to know if the user has authenticated and no other states are being kept. I believe that deploying state for a single variable is not justified.

Comment: What about using localstorage? You can check the localstorage state, for example if the key `your-app-isAuthenticated` is true, you can assume the user is authenticated.

Comment: Thank you @Kevin Yobeth. I cannot use localstorage, for I am storing an JWT when a user authenticates, which should only be stored in an httpOnly cookie for security reasons. Storing it in localstorage wouldn't solve my issue either, for if the variable was no longer found in localstorage (if the user had cleared history for instance), he would be redirected to the home page without knowing why. By passing a flag when the user is re-routed  to the home page, my home page would know that it needs to inform the user to authenticate once again.